# How to include Roku_Ads.brs library for the Roku Advertising Framework

Tags: google-dfp, roku

I'm trying to make midroll ads work with DFP on Roku and I'm having some trouble.

I'm reading the docs on using the Roku Advertising Framework (RAF) and it says to put `Library "Roku_Ads.brs"` into the code where I want to use RAF.  Since it uses the `Library` call, it leads me to assume that the library is included in Roku and doesn't have to be downloaded separately.

However, when I put `Library "Roku_Ads.brs"` at the top of my `lib/ads.brs` file, I always get the following error:

```
*** ERROR compiling /pkg:/source/lib/ads.brs:
Error loading file. (compile error &hb9) in pkg:/source/lib/ads.brs(1) 'Roku_Ads.brs'
```

What am I missing here?  Is there some `Roku_Ads.brs` file that I need to download from somewhere first?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to add the following line to your manifest:

```
bs_libs_required=roku_ads_lib
```